# react select styles and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

According to the [react-select docs](https://react-select.com/styles#select-props) I can gain access to my own arguments passed into the Select body like this:

```js
const customStyles = {
  menu: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    width: state.selectProps.width,
    borderBottom: '1px dotted pink',
    color: state.selectProps.menuColor,
    padding: 20,
  }),

  control: (_, { selectProps: { width }}) => ({
    width: width
  }),

  singleValue: (provided, state) => {
    const opacity = state.isDisabled ? 0.5 : 1;
    const transition = 'opacity 300ms';

    return { ...provided, opacity, transition };
  }
}
```

However if I have something like this in typescript

```js
const customStyles: SelectProps["styles"] = {
  valueContainer: (provided, { selectProps: { size } }) => {
    const px = {
      sm: "0.75rem",
      md: "1rem",
      lg: "1rem"
    };

    return {
      ...provided,
      padding: `0.125rem ${px[size]}` 
    };
  },

};
```

The `${px[size]}` part throws an error

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ sm: string; md: string; lg: string; }'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indicates the incoming `size` is an `any` type and typescript does not know if it is one of the keys of `sm` `md` `lg`.

**Way 01: use `cast` to inform typescript, size is one of the `sm` `md` `lg`**

```
const px = {
  sm: "0.75rem",
  md: "1rem",
  lg: "1rem"
};

px[size as 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg']
```

**Way 02: Have a type for `px` and use its key for casting**

```
type PxType = { [k in 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg']: string }

const px: PxType = {
  sm: "0.75rem",
  md: "1rem",
  lg: "1rem"
};

px[size as keyof PxType]
```